# Same height columns with more than one row on Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I'm trying to do a responsive columns layout with the same height using Bootstrap 3. I can do it when all columns are in the same row, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/aitorrodriguez/6sdbnwg6/

And another example here: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

But I have a problem when I try to do it with more than one row because I don't know what number of columns I will have and the row of columns will vary depending on the resolution:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>Test</p>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>Test</p>     
    </div>
</div>
```

What can I do? Anyone knows some solution or it's impossible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution but does the trick sometimes

```
.row { /*or the name of the wrapper*/
   overflow: hidden; 
}

.col-lg-4 { /*the column*/
    margin-bottom: -999px;
    padding-bottom: 999px;
}
```

Take a look at this more detailed [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/D4xdE/)

Comment: I need one more "jump" using cols, for example: "col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12". It's not possible?

Comment: Should be possible, It's better if you try yourself since i don't know the detail of your proyect and if this is the best solution for you. You can also add a new class for the margin and padding trick, instead of grabbing the `col-*`class

Comment: I'm trying but I think it's impossible to do because in "col-md-4" it doesn't works correctly. Thank you!